# Is it possible to auto-update native JavaFX apps?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to have a JavaFX application with native packaging (Windows as well as Linux) where the user can click a button to update to the latest version of the app (or have the update take place automatically).  This functionality doesn't appear to be built in.  Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a feature request [RT-22211](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22211) to allow [self-contained](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) JavaFX applications to be updated automatically.  This feature request is currently scheduled for implementation for Java 9.  In the meantime, take a look at the comments on the feature request which discuss various alternate mechanisms for auto-updating JavaFX applications.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution of how auto-updating could be done as long as the feature is not implemented yet (it will take a while until Java9)?

Comment: Try pinging [Danno Ferrin](https://github.com/shemnon) and see the suggestions of the feature request linked in the post.  Any suggestions are better posted on the feature request than here.

Comment: So, as of now, is UpdateFX still the best way to provide auto updates? No way to automatically update the bundled JRE yet?

Comment: @Lorthirk I have never used UpdateFX, so I cannot recommend for or against it.  There is nothing currently in the JRE to autoupdate self-contained applications.   You can track status by referring to the feature request linked in my answer (which is no longer scheduled for Java 9, but is in a tbd_major bucket).

Comment: [UpdateFX](https://github.com/vinumeris/updatefx) is a third party library that adds auto update mechanism for JavaFX bundled applications (but has some limitations anyway). I'm about to start a new application, would love to use JavaFX but auto updating is a crucial requirement...

Comment: https://reportmill.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/automatically-update-your-javapackager-applications/

Could help some people looking for a way.

Comment: There also seems to be [FXLauncher](https://github.com/edvin/fxlauncher), but I don't know if it is good or not, have not used it.